# Where can I find the mentioned More than one Method article?

Tags: reference-request, language-acquisition, chomsky

Chomsky mentions an article that I have never taken a look at in his talk at the University of Arizona "What is Special About Language?".

I've seen "Without Social Context?" but I've never seen the other one.

It's described to be an article in the journal of Cognitive Science. "More than One Method". Chomsky, "Well we know that there is one method for acquiring language, namely, statistical analysis of data, but is there another method, or does that do everything?"

Chomsky, "He claims, rightly or wrongly if you look at it, that [this invented example] can be handled with statistical analysis and therefor there is only one method... statistical analysis."

Comment: Could be Nick Chater or Morten Christiansen. Why not ask Chomsky himself? He usually replies to almost everyone. Incidentally, you can search *Cognitive Science* here http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1111/(ISSN)1551-6709

Comment: http://linguistics.mit.edu/user/chomsky/